# Java method-if isolated variable?

Tags: java, if-statement, methods

I'm making a program but i need to add a method to get a total amount for public services, but the problem its because the return variable is modified by a value which is in one if ... but if this value isolated .. that might be happening?

here is the code:

```
package primer.proyecto.programado;

import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Main 
{

    public static int servicios()
    {
        int servicios=0;
        int servivio11=0;
        int servivio22=0;
        int servivio33=0;
        int servivio44=0;

        String msg = "Servicios:";

        JCheckBox servicio1 = new JCheckBox ("Electricidad");
        JCheckBox servicio2 = new JCheckBox ("Agua");
        JCheckBox servicio3 = new JCheckBox ("Telefono");
        JCheckBox servicio4 = new JCheckBox ("Otros");

        Object[] msgContent = {msg,servicio1,servicio2,servicio3,servicio4};

        int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,msgContent,
                "Title", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

        boolean servicio1s = servicio1.isSelected();
        boolean servicio2s = servicio2.isSelected();
        boolean servicio3s = servicio3.isSelected();
        boolean servicio4s = servicio4.isSelected();

        if (servicio1s == true)
        {
            int servicio11 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    "Favor digite el monto a pagar por el servicio: Electricidad"));
        }
        if (servicio2s == true)
        {
            int servicio22 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    "Favor digite el monto a pagar por el servicio: Agua"));
        }
        if (servicio3s == true)
        {
            int servicio33= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    "Favor digite el monto a pagar por el servicio: Telefono"));
        }
        if (servicio4s == true)
        {
            int servicio44 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    "Favor digite el monto a pagar por el servicio: Otro"));
        }

        servicios=servicio11+servicio22+servicio33+servicio44;

        return servicios;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        servicios();    
    }
}
```

I'm using netbeans and a JavaApplication division...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please reduce your code to the minimum amount needed to illustrate your issue. Also provide example input and output and explain how the output differs from what you want.

Comment: Your code will not compile, because `servicio11`, `servicio22`, `servicio33` and `servicio44` are local variables to `if` statement blocks, and are not defined after all `if` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I **think** what you want is more like this:

```
int servicios = 0;

if (servicio1s == true){
    servicios += Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Favor digite el monto a pagar por el servicio: Electricidad"));
}

if (servicio2s == true){
    servicios += Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Favor digite el monto a pagar por el servicio: Agua"));
}

if (servicio3s == true){
    servicios += Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Favor digite el monto a pagar por el servicio: Telefono"));
}

if (servicio4s == true){
    servicios += Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Favor digite el monto a pagar por el servicio: Otro"));
}

return servicios;
```

Thus, servicios is 0 if all servicio booleans are false.  Is this your intent?

Answer (score 1):

All right-hand-side variables on this line:

```
servicios = servicio11 + servicio22 + servicio33 + servicio44;
```

are limited in scope to previous `if` statements so cannot be resolved. You need to make them visible in the same scope as your `servicios` method:

```
int servicio11 = 0;
if (servicio1s) {
   servicio11 = Integer.parseInt(...);
}
...
```